# how does yesod auth system work?

Tags: haskell, yesod

I'm trying to write custom `loginHandler` for my app, but the total lack of documentation on writing custom `YesodAuth` instances are quite irritating..

So here are my questions.

1. Which `Route`s are magically provided by `yesod-auth`? and what are the handlers that I have to provide?
2. and how do you write handlers? it seems I have to implement  a `loginHandler` for `YesodAuth` instance but won't there be multiple routes (log in, log out, create account, delete account, recover password .. )?

I don't want to write a total yesod-auth plugin myself, I'm just fine with simple login page. thanks!

Comment: have you read [Authentication and Authorization in Yesod](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/authentication-and-authorization) - also in a similar situation I found the [source](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/yesod-auth-1.4.13/docs/src/Yesod-Auth-Hardcoded.html) and the introduction to the [`Yesod.Auth.Hardcoded`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/yesod-auth-1.4.13/docs/Yesod-Auth-Hardcoded.html) module really helpful (I think it's the shortest one doing anything)

Comment: to you 1.) that should be the [routes defined here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/yesod-auth-1.4.13/docs/Yesod-Auth.html#t:Auth) (

Comment: for 2.) I would just look at the modules I linked above - IMO they are well documented